# jQuery append() does nothing

Tags: jquery, append

I can't get append() to work in any browser.

I want the "next" span to have a blue background and display the text "Next **hello**" on page load.

(This is some test code to make sure my jQuery is working; eventually I'll replace "hello" with something more informative, such as `"<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>".`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
             $('span.next').css('background-color', 'blue');
             $('span.next').append(' <b>hello</b>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
        <span class="next">Next</span>
</div>
```

The blue background line works fine, but the append does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you wan't to append the text 'hello' on any click event?

Comment: both the answer's working perfectly.If you have still doubt then tell.

Comment: I don't want any click event at this stage ... I'll cross that bridge when I get to it :-) for now I just want to dynamically append some text to what's already there, so "hello" is just to test my code ... but I can't make that work

Comment: I edited your question and put your code into a `code snippet`.  It runs just fine.

Comment: yes, you're right @ps2goat ... thanks. I guess the problem on my system must be some place else. Will have another hunt around.

Answer (score -1):

Here I have edited the [FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/hiwice/edit?html,js,output).
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
        <span class="next">Next</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
             $('span.next').css('background-color', 'blue');
   $(".nav").click(function(){
     $('span.next').append(' <b>hello</b>');
   });

    });
```

Comment: can you please explain ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: @shishir Pasting code without an explanation isn't helpful. You're also in using click events, which the OP doesn't mention.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I have only a limited knowledge of jQuery. The OP's code should work AFAIK.

Comment: @Carcigenicate both the answer works perfectly. If you have problem with less description then don't vote them down as both answers are perfectly working.

Comment: i think the person who is having limited knowledge of Jquery are not supposed to comment and down vote the answers done on jquery tags.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Except that spoon feeding someone code without an explanation isn't helpful at all. The point is to teach them what's wrong, not just give them a work around.

Comment: @shishir I'm not downvoting because it doesn't work, I'm downvoting because it's a bad answer. Knowledge of jQuery isn't required to determine that.

Comment: I think this depends on @cobberas63 to decide, which works or not.

Comment: As per my comment above, I don't want this tied to a click event, I want the text appended when the page loads. So the answer given is the same as my code with addition of the click event ... isn't it??

Comment: you want your text to be appended once the page loads?
[Check Here:](http://jsbin.com/hiwice/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score -3):

This is allready works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
             $('span.next').css('background-color', 'blue');
             $('span.next').append(' <b>hello</b>');
             $('span.next').append(' <br><b>hello</b></br>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
        <span class="next">Next</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer. Please explain how this differs from the OP's version.

Comment: @Carcigenicate snippet working fine.Can you explain how it is not useful?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Because this doesn't say what's wrong with the OP's code, you're just supplying a more verbose version that works.

Comment: @Carcigenicate then you should down vote the questioner also as things works in fiddle with code.

Comment: Looks exactly like my code, so why doesn't mine work on my system??

Comment: @cobberas63 probably you have a sintax error on the page

Comment: sorry man but this is not exactly your code this is the sample fiddle with included append one new line and i also say that in may answer your code is working fine.